# AngularJS timer wont stop

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm running the following code, i'm trying to when it gets to 10 seconds, stop the timer basically

```
 var mytimeout;
    $scope.startTimer = function() {
        $scope.counter = 0;
        $scope.onTimeout = function() {
            $scope.counter++;
            $log.info($scope.counter);
            if ($scope.counter == 10) {
                $scope.stop();
                $state.go($state.current.name, {}, {
                    reload: true
                })
            }
            mytimeout = $timeout($scope.onTimeout, 1000);

        }
        mytimeout = $timeout($scope.onTimeout, 1000);

    }

     $scope.stop = function(){
        $log.info("Stop");
        $timeout.cancel(mytimeout);
    }
```

The log goes like:

```
angular.js:10126 1
angular.js:10126 2
angular.js:10126 3
angular.js:10126 4
angular.js:10126 5
angular.js:10126 6
angular.js:10126 7
angular.js:10126 8
angular.js:10126 9
angular.js:10126 10
angular.js:10126 Stop
angular.js:10126 11
angular.js:10126 12
angular.js:10126 13
```

Comment: Try console.log(mytimeout) within $scope.stop. It may return undefined or false since $scope.onTimeout is not defined.

Comment: I don't see a `return` statement in that `if`. `mytimeout = $timeout(....` will be executed regardless of what happens in that `if`. Also `$timeout.cancel(mytimeout)` won't work either because right after the `if` you are redefining it.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 4):

Your counter is indeed stoppping, but you then reassign `mytimeout` after the if statement so the timer starts again. I'm guessing the $state.go() still runs but the counter continues in the console.

Instead, call the timer if less than 10, otherwise call the resolving function.

```
$scope.startTimer = function() {
    $scope.counter = 0;
    $scope.onTimeout = function() {
        $log.info($scope.counter);

        if($scope.counter < 10){
            mytimeout = $timeout($scope.onTimeout, 1000)
        }else{
            $scope.stop();
            $state.go($state.current.name, {}, {
                reload: true
            })
        }

        $scope.counter++;
    }

    mytimeout = $timeout($scope.onTimeout, 1000);
}
```